# $variable = header location

Tags: php

I can find hundreds of examples of "insert into header location", but I have not found any exaples where the `$variable = header` location.

Is this possible:

```
$error=header('Location: http://www.example.com/error.php');
```

Basicly I had 3 conditions if row not found in mysql.

So I set up the 3 conditions:

if condition1 $error="a statement"

if condition2 $error="SELECT `data`  FROM `table` WHERE `data`= 'default'";

if condition3 $error=header('Location: example.com/error.php');

and then if($result->num_rows =0) $error

In my case `$error` could be 3 different things, one of them being "redirect to the error page" but `$error=header('Location:blah');` causes 500 server error.

I altered my code so that I could use header location in the conventional manner, but would still like to know if `$var = header` location is possible.

The original code that prompted the question has been overwritten, I no longer have it to post.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: What would you expect that to do? And yes, it's possible, it just may not do whatever you think this should do.

Comment: Please post more code form this file for us to ID what the problem might be.

Comment: I have completely rewritten the code, so I no longer have it to post. I could reconstruct it but since I write code at a snails pace, you would have to wait a couple days. My php knowledge is very limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) returns type of void. You can not expect `$error` to be anything besides `null`.

If you are getting a 500 error, it is caused by something else (syntax error?).

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php

header() returns void, so, you can write `$error=header('Location: http://www.example.com/error.php');`, but it wont do much.

After `header('Location: ...');` you should call `exit;`.

Comment: `exit;` (it's a keyword, so you don't need the ())

Comment: I know, but I usually add `()`

Comment: You can _write_ `$error = header(...)`, it just won't _do_ much.

Comment: It's possible that the OP [rewrote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) the `header` function in which it does return something.

Comment: @Dave Now that's pretty darn hypothetical. :P

Comment: Basicly I had 3 conditions if row not found in mysql, if condition1 $error="a statement", if condition2 error='written in proper code - a new mysql row' and if condition3 $error=header('Location: http://www.example.com/error.php'); So I set up the 3 conditions and then if($result->num_rows =0) $error

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the 'header' function to anything, as it would always return void. A bit useless.

Comment: Must be why I couldn't find any examples of it. In my searching I also couldn't find any post like this saying it can't be done. Thank you to all who replied.